# Add user control and handle parent event c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I want to dynamically create an submitform containing various usercontrols that i create.

Ex:

```
<div class="fieldControl">
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="TextField" runat="server"><%=LabelText %></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The controls should be added based on an xml:

```
<Fields>
  <Group name="Main" text="Innhold">
    <Field type="TextBox" name="Name" text="Navn"></Field>
    <Field type="TextBox" name="Test" text="Test"></Field>
  </Group>
</Fields>
```

When i on my parent control Edit.ascx clicks on the save button. I want to handle this event on every added usercontrol.

Can you point me in what direction i should go, creating and handling save event?

Answer (score 0):

some pseudo-code:

```
    void building()
    {
        var items = getItemsFromXml();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var control = BuildControl(item);
            this.EventToHandle += control.PublicEventHandlerMethod();
            this.Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
```